# ArcGIS Online Groups for Public and Organization Accounts

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-collector

I need to share data with public accounts from my organizational account within ArcGIS Online. I don't want to make the data shareable to everyone, just within a group. But when I try to invite the public user to my organization group I get this generic error message:

[image: Generic Error Message]

If I create a group with the public account, I can't invite the organizational user and the organizational user can't find the group.

I may be barking up the wrong tree and this may be a limitation of ArcGIS public accounts, but I've been searching for a while and haven't found anything conclusive to that effect. Perhaps there actually is an error in the back-end?

---

FYI - I am try to share collector apps in my organization. We have about 7 tablets and I want to have a unique account for each tablet. I was hoping to have public accounts for each tablet. In addition we plan to share certain collector apps with members of the public, once again I don't want to share the app with *everyone*, but only certain members.

Comment: A group created by a public account may not invite an organization account user to be a member of the group

Comment: @Simon but can a organizational account invite a public account?

Comment: Ask ESRI's support

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the help: 
http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/own-groups.htm

You can only invite people who have the same type of account that you have. If you have an organizational account, you can only invite organizational accounts to join your group. If you have a public account, you can only invite public accounts to join your group. In this case you might want to have level 1 users who are just going to be viewing the content accessing it.

If you plan to use Collector that requires a named user with a level 2 org account. Public accounts will not work with Collector and cannot sign in.

Answer (score 2):

As Russ mentioned, you can only use Collector with a Level 2 user that is part of an organisation's account. Collector always requires a login even if you are editing public data.

There is an option with Survey123 [to create public surveys](https://geonet.esri.com/groups/survey123/blog/2016/11/10/getting-started-with-public-surveys) which can be completed without a login within the mobile app. However in order to do this the data must be shared publically.